# MYSQL UNION required with Duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have DCHDR Table with unique records as DC_No field and 
DCDTL which is a transaction table, which would have duplicate DC_Nos with different products and qty.

From the below MYSQL line, I am able to join, union 2 tables and the result is as per my requirement only when duplicate records in DCDTL are not identical,

i.e, Below example records are in DCDTL only 1 is displayed and the second record is not.

Example: fields in DCDTL and data -

```
DC_Nos, Product_Desc, Nos, Qty  
111     Oxygen 99.99,  4,  10 
111     Oxygen 99.99,  4,  10
```

I know UNIQUE will remove duplicates in the table, but is there any other way to display even identical records of DCDTL Table. Pl suggest.

```
    SELECT DC_No, DC_date, T.DC_Nos, T.Product_Desc,  T.Nos, T.Qty
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
    UNION
    SELECT DC_No, DC_date, T.DC_Nos, T.Product_Desc, T.Nos, T.Qty
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
```

BELOW IS THE SAMPLE DATA OF BOTH THE TABLES AND THE DESIRED RESULT:

DCHDR Table:

```
 DC_date     DC_Nos  
 2013-01-01  111
 2013-01-02  112
 2013-01-03  113
```

DCDTL Table:

```
 DC_Nos, Product_Desc, Nos, Qty  
 111     Oxygen 99.99,  4,  10 
 111     Oxygen 99.99,  4,  10 
 111     Nitrogen,      9,  14
 112     Nitrogen,      8,  29
 113     Zero Air,      4,  15
```

Result required:

```
 DC_date     DC_Nos  Product_Desc, Nos, Qty
 2013-01-01  111     Oxygen 99.99,  4,  10
 2013-01-01  111     Oxygen 99.99,  4,  10
 2013-01-01  111     Nitrogen,      9,  14
 2013-01-02  112     Nitrogen,      8,  29
 2013-01-03  113     Zero Air,      4,  15
```

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: @JW.           I am unable to get the tabs after editing, kindly excuse, but the result required is mentioned in the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to have `UNION` of `LEFT and RIGHT JOIN` when this can be achieved using `INNER JOIN`?

```
SELECT  a.DC_DATE, b.*
FROM    DCHDR a
        INNER JOIN DCDTL b
            ON a.DC_Nos = b.DC_Nos
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44792/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I have tried even UNION ALL, it does not give the result I want, it is creating almost double the records present in the DCDTL. Currently there are 530 records in DCDTL, AFTER ADDING 'ALL', the result is 1060

Comment: why do you need to use `UNION`?

Comment: @JW I was wondering the same thing. I have a feeling the sample data above isn't really adequate for us to understand what OP is trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you desired result -

```
SELECT * FROM dchdr
  LEFT JOIN dcdtl -- or maybe INNER JOIN
    ON dchdr.DC_Nos = dcdtl.DC_Nos
```

Is it what you want?